# Prototypejs and Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, socket.io

I'm working with an older project which uses PrototypeJS pretty heavily. I have a class which looks like:

```
var FooSocket = Class.create({
  ...

  listen: function(host, port) {
    this._socket = io.connect(host + ':' + port);

    ...
  }
});
```

Socket.IO is included and available to the browser, however I'm getting the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'`

How can I access socket.io from within a prototype class?

Comment: What do you get if you log `io` to the browser console? Does it work outside the class?

Comment: it's available: [Object]

Comment: Has the io variable been used for something else? The original (as generated by socket.io.js may has been overwritten.